# How to deal with the product between matrix [None, 32, 32] and matrix [32, 32] with `tf.matmul`?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix, tensorflow, neural-network

Before building a DNN model, I need to have the product of two matrixes: `[None, 32, 32]` and `[32, 32]`

Since I know that this method works (from the example of `MNIST`)

```
x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
l = tf.matmul(x, W)
```

I try this one on my question

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None, 64, 64])
w = t.Variable(tf.random_normal([64, 64], 0, 0.3))
l = tf.matmul(x, w)
```

But it is wrong.

--
I know that if `w = t.Variable(tf.random_normal([constant, 64, 64], 0, 0.3))`, this product could work. But I need the `w` to be the two-dimension matrix `[64, 64]`.

Could I have one method that makes this product between `[None, 32, 32]` and `[32, 32]` successful?

Comment: [None, 32, 32] is 3-dimensional and therefore not a matrix. Do you want to multiply every matrix of the [None, 32, 32] tensor along the 0th axis with the [32, 32] matrix? (and get a result of shape [None, 32, 32]?)

Comment: @BlueSun Yes! That's what I want! Do you have any methods?

Answer (score 1):

This method solves my question

```
tf.einsum('ijk,kl->ijl', x, w)
```

And this is the [wiki](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum)